# Tie a yellow ribbon VS kisses for me

Tags: cover

"Tie a yellow ribbon by the old Oak tree" and "kisses for me, save all your kisses for me" from the Eurovision are the same song? If it is, who copied from whom?

Comment: Although stylistically similar, these are two totally different songs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, even though [Save all Your Kisses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Save_Your_Kisses_for_Me) was originally written in 1974, two years before it became a hit, [Tie a Yellow Ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_a_Yellow_Ribbon_Round_the_Ole_Oak_Tree) was a hit the year before, in 1973, so you'd have to say that was the 'original' in that respect.

It has to be said, though, that songs of that style were not a new phenomenon, even outside Eurovision, though Eurovision itself may have been the source of a lot of them.

You could even perhaps claim that [Tom Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Jones_discography)' Green Green Grass of Home beat them both by nearly a decade - though I very much doubt that was the first 'prison' or even 'regret' record.

[Paper Lace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Lace) would also have a claim to the title of 'song that most makes you want to throw the radio out of the window' with Billy Don't be a Hero - & I'm not even going to add a link to Rolf Harris' Two Little Boys ;-)